# WPF resources in an assembly

Tags: wpf, resources

Is there to browse the WPF resources in a WPF assembly in .NET with Lutz's reflector?

Answer (score 3):

There is a BAML addin for Reflector.
http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1805#DownloadId=9088